# Ruby on Rails 5 one to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm struggling with a basic ruby on rails association. I have an Article which has an Operation. An operation can however belong to many instances of Article. In the Article class I have specified `has_one :operation`. The Articles table has a operation_id column of type integer. When I try to access the Operation on an instance of Article (article) in the tests: `puts article.operation` I get the following error:

> ArticleTest#test_test: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
>   SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: operations.article_id: SELECT 
>   "operations".* FROM "operations" WHERE "operations"."article_id" = ?
>   LIMIT ?
>       test/models/article_test.rb:6:in block in

From the error it becomes apparent that rails is looking in the operations table whereas it should look in the article table for the association.

I have tried to add `belongs_to: article` in the Operations model but it does not change the error. I'm sure I'm missing something but I can't seem to figure it out using the documentation and similar topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it you need to establish a 'belongs_to' relationship between articles and operations.

Change

```
has_one :operation
```

to

```
belongs_to :operation
```

And in your operation model:

```
has_many :articles
```

You'll need to give your articles an operation_id:

```
rails g migration addOperationIdToArticles operation_id:integer
rake db:migrate
```

Then try the command again. At the moment no articles have an operation_id, so none will belong to any operations, however you can assign a relationship with:

```
article.update_attributes(operation_id: whatever)
```

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. The problem I have with adding an article_id in the operations table is that a single instance of Operation can belong to numerous articles. Having the article_id in the operations table is not feasable then (at least, I think)

Comment: Apologies I skimread your question - it looks like you want an article to belong_to an operation rather than having one? I'll update my answer

Comment: I think that is what I want, apologies, I'm struggling with RoR associations still.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it makes sense now. I can now access the operation via an article, exactly what I wanted, thanks! edit: can accept in 3 minutes

Comment: No worries! Happy to help :)